# Slider with two Handlers using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement to Rank two Groups as below.

Group A &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Group B
  **100**------------------0--------------**100**

Can anyone help me please.......

Comment: How far have you got? Were did you get stuck? You might want to take a look at jQuery-UI.

Answer (score 0):

Simple JQuery UI shoudl suffice:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range-vertical

Comment: Hi guys,Thanks a lot for your Comments,i got solution for this problem.If any need solution please feel free to ask me.:-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like this:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/